# Hive RLIKE on a list of strings

Tags: regex, hive, rlike

I have 2 tables, one with long string + int values, the other with short strings, i would like to match each row in table1 to NOT contain any value in table2

table1 values:
'**i like my iphone now**',
'**iphone is great**',
'**this is also here**'

table2 values:
'**iphone**'
'**galaxy**'

i need the output to be only row 3 in table1
but when i do this:

```
select * from table1 a, table2 b 
where NOT (a.input RLIKE concat('(^|.* )', TRIM(b.exclude_word), '( .*|$)'));
```

it doesn't work because `table1 a, table2 join` is full outer join and i will always be left with values duplicated that don't match.